# rake:stats equivalent for python/django

Tags: python, django

Since rake:stats provides a nice visual of current codebase is there anything equivalent in django which is as easy to use? I am looking for a visual display like rake does in a tabular form or really in any form which can be later parsed to a desired structure.

[image: http://s3.amazonaws.com/37assets/svn/756-bcx-code-stats.png]

Comment: Do you just want to know the code's test coverage? Or you want the extra stats like this about how many lines exists in different categories?

Comment: more interested in different categories, seems like a really useful functionality.

Comment: [Pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) reports some code metrics. [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/) for test coverage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Pedro Romano,
a combination of pylint and coverage.py could achive this and I was able to use that to have report of something similar.